# Adding Short Description to Long Description Tab in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, php

I currently have my short description being called in view.phtml

```
            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
            <div class="short-description">
                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
```

I'd like to add this to my long description (which is currently being called by description.phtml).

I've tried adding this bit of code to the description.phtml

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?>
```

However, when I do that the tabs disappear altogether. Is there a way to possibly merge the short and long description in Magento, or just a way to add the short description into the description tab without it breaking?

Comment: could you please clear me, you want to display product Description filed value in Description tab with short description in product view page right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code to get `short_description` value in `description.phtml`

```
<?php $_short_description = $this->getProduct()->getShortDescription();?>
```

Then add this

```
<?php if ($_short_description): ?>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_short_description, 'short_description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

copy core file form this url app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml to app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml

if you want to combine short and log description togather then try below code

```html
<?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
<?php $_short_description = $this->getProduct()->getShortDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description && $_short_description): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description')." ".$this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_short_description, 'shortDescription') ?>
    </div>
<?php elseif($_description) : ?>
 <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description');?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

if you just want to place short then remove long description code from above

Hope this will help you out

Thanks